# Writing into multiple MySQL databases async

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, multi-master-replication

I am using AWS RDS so database replication between regions are impossible.

My application written in PHP and deployed on all regions, i am looking for a fast and reliable way to achieve that.

I am going to make MySQL connections :

SET @@auto_increment_increment= NUMBER_OF_WRITEABLE_DATABASES;

SET @@auto_increment_offset = REGION_ID ;

so AI pk's will be unique all over regions.

And my current plan is keeping a query log table with fields => id,queries,status,user_id. It will log all insert,update,delete queries into queries field in same page load.

**Status Codes:**

Status 0 => not executed

Status 1 => successfully executed on all regions

Status 2 => failed

Status 3 => failed with affected rows not match

**Example Row:**

id=>1
queries=>
INSERT INTO PROFILES VALUES (1,{USER_ID},'Username','Email')##SEPERATOR##AFFECTED_COUNT
UPDATE USERS SET last_modified='2012-12...' where id={USER_ID}##SEPERATOR##AFFECTED_COUNT
status=0
user_id=>{USER_ID}

and there will be a daemon which reads records which status != 1 and will process them on all regions without commit , once all run without error it will commit or roll back in case of error.

That is what i thought and going to use.

My question is there any more decent/tested approach to that scenario or is there any problem about my approach.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

My initial thought is that you are going down the wrong path if you are trying to use RDS as a solution to enforce unique record ID's across multiple regions. I would think you might want to rethink your actual need for uniqueness across regions or enforce uniqueness using multiple columns (i.e. an autoincrement plus a region identifier). That could be read and put into some eventually consistent data store for read purposes.

Comment: I'd agree.  If there really needs to be cross-regional replication, RDS is the wrong choice here.  As an example: If the OP needed to add another region, this strategy would be problematic.

Comment: I agree with Mike - if you are implementing by yourself full blown database replication - you are doing it wrong. Your auto increment trick is nice though...

Answer (score 0):

You're making a commendable effort, but as the other commenters have stated, your solution isn't viable, for a number of reasons.

You don't really want to use auto_increment_offset and auto_increment_increment at the session level.  You want to set those at the server level.  If RDS won't let you do that, this is another reason why RDS is probably not the best solution.

If I came out and suggested that you deploy a global network of MySQL servers (EC2, not RDS) in a multi-master ring, where data replicates 1 => 2 => 3 => 4 => 1 and each server ignores incoming replication messages with its own server id, my fellow MySQL DBAs would accuse me of having lost my mind and setting you up for a difficult-to-manage situation; **however**, I am convinced that this would be a *much easier* solution than what you have proposed, because at least, then, the data would be changing around the world in pretty much the same order in which it actually changed -- which would reduce the likelihood of conflicting updates originating from multiple locations.  MySQL replication is asynchronous, in the sense that server 1 does not wait for a transaction to be committed on server 2 before returning success to the client (indicating that the transaction has committed), but don't confuse that fact with the fact that it *is* sequential -- transactions are replicated on each server in the order in which they were committed. (New options in MySQL 5.6 allow some exceptions to this by with parallel replication threads, but that isn't significant to this discussion).

Since you have devised a scheme for avoiding conflicting auto-increment values, your bigger problems are likely to come from updates and deletes.  In the scenario I just described, if server 2 deleted a record and server 4 deleted the same record at the same time, then server 4 would stop replicating incoming events when it received the delete from server 2, because the "rows affected" would have been different.  Your scenario would similarly fail.  The difference is that using actual MySQL replication, nothing happening after the conflicting event happened, so until you resolved that conflict, at least your data would not diverge any further into inconsistency because of the sequential nature discussed above and the fact that MySQL replication *completely stops* whenever a conflict is encountered.  In a ring of master servers, the server that has stopped replicating continues collecting a log of replication events from the upstream systems, but execution halts and the data on that server is frozen unless changed locally until the conflict is resolved and replication restarted.

Note also that in your scenario, you need to preserve "from" and "to" values for each column on updates, because you can't roll anything back unless you know that it rolls back to.

That being noted, a rollback needs to occur in real-time, not later.  If I transfer money between two bank accounts, and for some reason that transfer needs to roll back, I need to see that while I'm using the bank's web site -- the bank can't roll that transaction back in the middle of the night just because one of their servers has a different balance in my bank account.

Here's a thought: In your scenario, it the account I was transferring "to" was consistent among all the servers, but the account I was transferring "from" was not, then I wonder... would your setup roll back the withdrawal from the "from" account, but leave the deposit in the "to" account?  I think it might.

Keep in mind that you are limited by the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).  No system can be globally consistent, available, and tolerate isolation among the nodes.  At best, you can pick any two.

With that thought, the question I have is this:  why do all of the nodes in your global system need to be synchronized?  If the main reason is performance, consider the possibility of deploying a single global master server, with read replicas distributed among the regions.  Write your application with two pools of database connection threads so that most `SELECT` queries go to the local read replica, while `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, and `CALL` (stored procedures that update data), are sent to the global master server.  Your biggest worry, then, becomes the fact that you only have [eventual consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) on the read replicas.  With properly-sized servers and well-written queries, this is very fast (subject to the laws of physics for global travel of optical and electrical signals) but it is not instantaneous.  What you have to do to accomplish this is for sessions that have recently made changes to the database, their reads may need to hit the global master -- if you place an order, you need to see the order immediately, so the master might be the best place to look, right away.  Later, looking at the local replica will work.  You're still out of scope for RDS with this, because of the cross-regional issue... but MySQL on EC2 is a good fit.

Read replicas impose a very small load on the master, but even this load can be mitigated by connecting a single read replica to the master and then connecting the downstream read replicas to that intermediate server.

Setting `slave_compressed_protocol` = 1 on the masters and the replicas will enable the machines to use compressed connections for transferring the replication events.  I have found this to be anywhere from 3:1 to 10:1 depending on the nature of the data being replicated and the delay of compressing and decompressing the data seems insignificant.

Additionally, you could set up a second master, adjacent to the primary master (perhaps in a different A/Z), link those two servers with master-master replciation, chain the read replicas to the 2nd master, use auto increment increment and offsets appropriately, but **do not write to or read from** to the second master under normal conditions.  Why would you do this?  This way, you have a 2nd global master that could be placed into service immediately in case of failure of the primary master by redirecting your application to access it.

Of course, the nature of your application plays a large factor in how much global integration is actually required.  Solving this problem will require you to rethink how the application works, to determine whether architectural changes are needed.

As a DBA, I don't like some of the restrictions and flexibility constraints that RDS imposes on me.  All I really get in return for the loss-of-control is a relative ease of backups and point-in-time restoration... which I like... but, to me, these don't make up for the restrictions.

---

Footnote: In the 3rd paragraph, I said "transactions are replicated on each server in the order in which they were committed."   But that doesn't necessarily mean in the real-world wall-clock actual-order in which they were committed... it actually means the order in which they were committed to each server relative to the other transactions being committed by that server... so a transaction on Server #1 that actually committed before a different transaction on Server #3 might arrive at server #4 after the transaction from #3 instead of before it, depending on how long the transaction took to propagate through server #2 and be committed on server #3.  However, this is still "true enough" in principle, because if the transaction on #1 is perceived at server #3 as conflicting with whatever happened on #3, it will not actually replicate to #4 because #3 will stop replicating.